# hyperlink in gridview error

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="" 
       onclick="javascript:w= window.open(
               <%# Eval("booking_id","hideFromStartborrow.aspx?booking_id={0}")%>,
               'mywin','left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=0,resizable=0');">
     new  Window</asp:HyperLink>
```

I want to send it to another one, but it does not.And want to make the page smaller.

Comment: I am not able to get anything from this

Comment: kindly elaborate your question

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Hyperlink

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("hideFromStartborrow.aspx?booking_id={0}", Eval("booking_id")) %>' onclick="javascript:w= window.open(this.href,'DownloadImage','left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=0,resizable=0');return false;">Open</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

`OnClientClick` will be executed in the client side and only if it returns true,it will be posted back to server..If its false then nothing will happen.. Inorder to deal directly with server side use `onClick`..Here you are using both javascript and server side code so i would recommend `onclientclick`..